# How can an outlet be nil even though it has been set

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, null, iboutlet

I have a `viewController` with two `embedded` `viewControllers` through `containers`. I then created `outlets` from the parent `viewController's` `containers` to the parent `class`. I want to either hide or show the `containers` depending on certain conditionals.

But if I simply write:

```
  @IBOutlet var twoArmsContainer: UIView! {
        didSet {
            print("SETTING TWO ARM")
        }
    }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        twoArmsContainer.isHidden = true //container is nil
}
```

Then it crashes with `twoArmsContainer` being `nil` *after* the print in `didSet` has been triggered. How is it possible that the outlet is set, but then becomes `nil`? I have tried hiding it inside `didSet` and that works fine:

```
  @IBOutlet var twoArmsContainer: UIView! {
        didSet {
            print("SETTING TWO ARM")
            twoArmsContainer.isHidden = true //WORKS
        }
    }
```

What else can I say? The `class` I'm working in `inherits` from another `class` so there is a `super.viewDidLoad`. Not sure if that is relevant. I tried putting the `outlets` in the `super class` but with the same results. I also tried removing and readding the `outlets` again. Have never experienced this problem before. Let me know if I should show more code; perhaps the entire `class`. Not really sure what's relevant as I'm clueless of where to start.

Comment: I think the container is load after the viewDidLoad. You should give a try by placing your code in the viewDidAppear, just to check

Comment: @CZ54 Ah, interesting, I'll check!

Comment: How are you creating the view controller instance?  Is it being created from the storyboard?

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt - double check that you set the `IBOutlet` correctly. I just gave it a quick try and cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: All the views are always ready for being used right after viewDidLoad is called! 
What @CZ54 says is actually about the actual embedding process of the child view controller into to that container views which happens a bit later than viewDidLoad is called.

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt You problem interested me. Could you provide a small example project where I can reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out what was wrong; an issue impossible to detect without access to the code, so in retrospect I should have posted both the parent `class` and `container` `class`. Sorry about that.

Anyway the issue was that the `container` `viewController` inherited from the `parent` `viewController`. This enabled me to share code in the two `container` `viewControllers`.

So the structure was basically this:

```
class WizardChooseArmViewController: WizardViewController {
...
```

This is the `parent` `viewController` which inherits from a base `viewController`. Then the `container` `viewControllers` looked like this:

```
final class WizardTwoArmsViewController: WizardChooseArmViewController {
...
```

Apparently it's a bad idea for `containers` to inherit from its `parent`, so I refactored and changed it to:

```
final class WizardTwoArmsViewController: WizardViewController {
...
```

Not quite sure why its not possible for `containers` to `inherit` from its `parent`. Would be great if someone could brief me.